# How to upLoad three (3) images on click per image using Glide

Tags: java, android

It's not showing any errors, but when I click upload on the image images are selected in all the image views.

The first code is here

```
mImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }
});
mImg1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }
});
mImg2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }
});
```

This is my code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).into(mImg);

    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).into(mImg1);
    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).into(mImg2);
    }
}
```

I tried searching on Google, but I could not find exactly what am looking for.

What I want is when I upload the image on click on imageview, it should only upload the selected image in one imageView, not in all three

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is you're using the same requestCode (RESULT_LOAD_IMG) for all three image views. When the user selects an image, the onActivityResult method is triggered with the same requestCode for all three image views, causing all of them to be updated.

To fix this issue, you need to use different request codes for each startActivityForResult call.

```
mImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startImagePickerForResult(RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }
});
mImg1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startImagePickerForResult(RESULT_LOAD_IMG_1);
    }
});
mImg2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startImagePickerForResult(RESULT_LOAD_IMG_2);
    }
});

private void startImagePickerForResult(int requestCode) {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, requestCode);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMG_1:
                Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).into(mImg);
                break;
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMG_2:
                Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).into(mImg1);
                break;
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMG_3:
                Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).into(mImg2);
                break;
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: And the solution is straight on point

Comment: @KerubAngel Happy to help!